# シェルスクリプトで特定のコマンドを無視する方法はないですか？

Tags: docker, shellscript

AWS EC2 用のセットアップシェルスクリプトを dockerfile に移植しようと思い

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY setup.sh /root/
RUN bash /root/setup.sh
```

という Dockerfile を描いて 
`docker build -t test -f Dockerfile .`
で実行してみたのですが

```
/root/setup.sh: 8: /root/setup.sh: sudo: not found
```

と言われます

sudo を消せばいいだけなのですが
できれば setup ファイルそのままの状態で流用できれば
EC2用とdocker用で2重管理しなくてすみます

また sudo をインストールすれば解決しそうですが
docker 内ではどうせ root でしか作業しないので
sudo コマンド自体を無視するようにできないでしょうか

alias sudo=''

みたいなことを描いてみたんですがやはり
`sudo: command not found`
になります

setup.sh のエラー箇所まではこんな感じです

```
#!/bin/bash
#alias sudo=''

PYENV=~/.pyenv
PYENV_BIN=$PYENV/bin

##Install git and python
sudo yum -y install git
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git $PYENV

echo -e "\nexport PYENV_ROOT=$PYENV" | sudo tee -a ~/.bash_profile  >> /dev/null
echo -e "\nexport PATH=$PYENV_BIN:$PATH" | sudo tee -a ~/.bash_profile  >> /dev/null
```

Comment: alias は interactive mode でしか利用できませんので、例えば sudo を関数化してしまう方法が考えられます。`function sudo { "$@"; }`

Comment: うまくいきました！　ありがとうございます！　結局 yum も入ってなかったので setup には手を入れないとダメみたいですが勉強になりました

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(コメントより)

alias は interactive mode でしか利用できませんので、例えば sudo を関数化してしまう方法が考えられます。`function sudo { "$@"; }`